# How to write test case for Apex class if Some filed are mapped

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

I have written test case but i am not able to improve percentage of the class

```
public with sharing class Handler_CreateOrderlineItems {
 public Set<Id> setContractIds;
 public map<Id,ContractLineItem__c> mapContractIdToItems;
 public List<OrderLineItem__c > lstOrderLineItems;

 public Handler_CreateOrderlineItems ()
    {
        setContractIds= new Set<Id>();
        mapContractIdToItems= new map<Id,ContractLineItem__c>();
        lstOrderLineItems= new List<OrderLineItem__c >();
    }

    public void onAfterInsert(List<Order__c> lstNew)
    {
        lstOrderLineItems= new List<OrderLineItem__c >();

        for(Order__c objOrder : lstNew)
        {
           setContractIds.add(objOrder.Contract__c);
        }

         if(setContractIds.size() > 0)
        {
            for(ContractLineItem__c objCLI :[select id,Name,Line_Number__c,Product__c,Discount_Amount__c,Quantity__c,Contract__c,Item_Price__c, Unit_Price__c 
                                                from ContractLineItem__c where Contract__c IN :setContractIds])

            {
                mapContractIdToItems.put(objCLI .id,objCLI );
            }
        }
          for( Order__c objOrId : lstNew)
          {
          for(ID objOLItem : mapContractIdToItems.keyset())
            {
               OrderLineItem__c objOItems = new OrderLineItem__c();

                if(mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Name != Null)
                {
                    objOItems .Name = mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Name;
                }

                if(mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Quantity__c != Null)
                {
                    objOItems .Quantity__c= mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Quantity__c ;
                }

                if(mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Unit_Price__c  != Null)
                {
                    objOItems .Unit_Price__c = mapContractIdToItems.get(objOLItem ).Unit_Price__c ;
                }

                if(objOrId .Id != Null)
                {
                 objOItems .Order__c = objOrId .id;
                }
                lstOrderLineItems.add(objOItems );
          }
          }

        if(lstOrderLineItems.size() > 0)
        {
            try
            {insert lstOrderLineItems;}
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
}
}
```

--------------------------my Testcase------------------

```
@isTest
private class Test_Handler_CreateOrderlineItems {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
System.debug('****hi ****');
    // TO DO: implement unit test
    Handler_CreateOrderlineItems gq =new Handler_CreateOrderlineItems();
    System.debug(gq +'****gq ****');
    Order__c objorder = new Order__c();
    Contract__c cont=new Contract__c();
    OrderLineItem__c objOli = new OrderLineItem__c();

     Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'testname';
    acc.Email__c = 'abcemail@gmail.com';
    acc.Mobile__c= '7446760472';
    acc.Phone = '7446760472';
    acc.Website='www.googleyajoo.com';


    insert acc;
    System.debug(acc+'****acc****');

    objorder.Name = 'test name';
     System.debug(objorder +'****objorder1****');
    objorder.Order_Number__c = 11;
    objorder.Account__c = acc.id;
    objorder.Subscription_type__c = 'Monthly' ;
    //objorder.Order_Date__c = '01/01/2013';
    objorder.Order_type__c = 'Sales';
    objorder.Order_Amount__c =1000;
    System.debug(objorder +'****objorder****');  

    insert objorder;


    ContractLineItem__c cli=new ContractLineItem__c();

    cont.Name='Test';
    //cli.Discount_Amount__c=2;

    insert cont;
      }
}
```

Comment: Amit, your question needs more detail (such as code) to be answerable.

Comment: Amit you can edit your question to add code of the test class and the class that you want to cover.

Comment: plz help me to write the test class

Comment: Can you share your test class, and explain us what parts you're not able to test ? The better we understand what you're stuck on, the better we can help!

Comment: plz see my test class it works fine but code coverage only 50%

Comment: @AmitSingh There are many decision making statements in your class. Make sure all of those cases are covered in the test class to improve the test code coverage.

Comment: @Azinq  i have tried lot but i m not getting

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can help get you sorted and pointed in the right direction.

First, it's always helpful to create a RunAs user. If you don't, your test will run as the system Admin rather than as a Standard User or other profile that will normally use your page. To do that, you can use code similar to this:

```
private class TestRunAs {
   public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
      // Setup test data
      // This code runs as the system user
      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
      User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');


      System.runAs(u) {
      // The following code runs as user 'u' 
      System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
      System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); }
   }
}
You can nest more than one runAs method. For example:

@isTest
private class TestRunAs2 {

   public static testMethod void test2() { 

      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
      User u2 = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email='newuser@testorg.com', 
         EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
         LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
         TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='newuser@testorg.com');

      System.runAs(u2) {
         // The following code runs as user u2. 
         System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
         System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 

         // The following code runs as user u3. 
         User u3 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserName='newuser@testorg.com'];
         System.runAs(u3) {
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
         }

         // Any additional code here would run as user u2.
      }
   }
}
```

Your runAs user can be called from a class method or a utility class like one of the above.

Next thing is that you have at least two methods I see that you need to test which are in the code section below:

```
if(lstOrderLineItems.size() > 0)
    {
        try
        {insert lstOrderLineItems;}
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

In essence, you need to create 2 methods. One where the `lstOrderLineItems.size() > 0` and the insert is successful, and another where the insert fails, but is caught by the exception block. So, what kind of data do you need to create differently that will allow you to create a `lstOrderLineItems` that will fail an insert?

I'm guessing that part of the issue you're currently having with your test class is that you've not looked to see what the required fields are for objects:

```
Order__c objorder = new Order__c();
Contract__c cont=new Contract__c();
OrderLineItem__c objOli = new OrderLineItem__c();
```

You can do that by going to the [ObjectReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) to get the SF required fields. Your org may have additional fields that are required. You'll need to check the objects in your org to see what those are. Now, why would an OLI fail to insert? Two possibilities that come to mind are that the Pricebook ID or Pricebook2 items aren't valid. Another would be that the Contract has expired the account isn't active. I'm confident you can come up with other reasons too.

There are some special things you'll need to do when it comes to getting the pricebook ID for OLI, you'll need to use [getStandardPricebookId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_getStandardPricebookId). See the link for more on inserting a Product2, Price, etc. That should help a great deal towards moving you along in your test class.